# Angular unit testing: $httpBackend.flush() causing $$route be 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to create unit test for server request failure:

Test:

```
  it('should progress $http on error', function () {
        httpBackend.whenPOST("/paymentUrl").respond(503);
        scope.progress();
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/paymentFailure');
     });
```

Code:

```
app.factory('$preventErrorReload', ['$route',
function ($route) {
    return function ($scope) {
        var lastRoute = $route.current;
        $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            if (lastRoute.$$route.templateUrl === $route.current.$$route.templateUrl) {
                $scope.$broadcast('locationChangedWithoutReload', $route.current);
                $route.current = lastRoute;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

And I am getting this error:
I suspect this is something caused by the `httpBackend.flush()` call but not too sure as to why, or what is happening

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'lastRoute.$$route')
```

Maybe someone knows why it is not working?

Comment: What do you expect `$route.current` to be in a test?

Comment: every other test runs correctly with a normal route of `''` for some reason when flush is called, it fails (just rebuilt his example)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't figure out how to solve it... Has anybody managed to fix this ?